# Using Curl to get Podbean Analytics - Can use auth to get access token but next request fails

Tags: curl, analytics

I am trying to access Podbean Analytic reports as outlined in API documentation:

https://developers.podbean.com/podbean-api-docs/#api-Analytics-Podcast_download_analytic_reports

Step 1.
Get Access Token By Client ID and Client Secret  is pretty straight forward and can achieve this  by Culr cmd and  my php script

```
`curl -u {client_id}:{client_secret} https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/token -X POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' `
```

this returns:

```
`{"access_token":"599d6a81a3c4e2464370f62dee5a987782899233","expires_in":604800,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"podcast_read episode_read podcast_update episode_publish private_members podcast_read episode_read"}`
```

Step2 According to documentation is:

```
`curl https://api.podbean.com/v1/analytics/podcastEngagementReports   -G -d 'access_token={access_token}' -d 'podcast_id={podcast_id}' -d 'year=2018'`
```

so I have tried filling the access token and podcast id and year in as below

```
`curl https://api.podbean.com/v1/analytics/podcastEngagementReports -d 'access_token=599d6a81a3c4e2464370f62dee5a987782899233'  -d 'podcast_id:Ajv6jiApCl8' -d 'year=2021'`
```

which returns:

```
`*   Trying 50.16.246.155:443...
* Connected to api.podbean.com (50.16.246.155) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: ALPN, offering http/1.1
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
 POST /v1/analytics/podcastEngagementReports HTTP/1.1
 Host: api.podbean.com
 User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
 Accept: */*
 Content-Length: 92
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Wed, 18 May 2022 16:20:06 GMT
< Server: Podbean
< Set-Cookie: AWSELB=1B8D7B911088DD70D274A300F88C43FD629F84AA56E0B7E3364E107CF9C4C26FC0D327AC12FE5459C9115FDA4057F3A30A8E9DEB9AD36059EBB4EB0F34EBC86015C2E32C2C;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=300
< Set-Cookie: AWSELBCORS=1B8D7B911088DD70D274A300F88C43FD629F84AA56E0B7E3364E107CF9C4C26FC0D327AC12FE5459C9115FDA4057F3A30A8E9DEB9AD36059EBB4EB0F34EBC86015C2E32C2C;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=300;SECURE;SAMESITE=None
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Service"
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host api.podbean.com left intact`
```

- A 401 Unautherised Header.

I have tried saving the   first Auth call in a local cookie using

```
 `curl -u {client_id}:{client_secret} https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/token -X POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' -c cookies.txt -L`
```

It doesn't make any difference.
I am brand new to Curl as of yesterday, no doubt I am misunderstanding how to use it. I have read numerous threads on here regarding Curl and API and am not seeing what I am missing

Any pointers would be appreciated.
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I have it working

```
curl https://api.podbean.com/v1/analytics/podcastEngagementReports -d 'access_token=599d6a81a3c4e2464370f62dee5a987782899233'  -d 'podcast_id:Ajv6jiApCl8' -d 'year=2021'`
```

does not work until I remove all the single quotes around the variables and in add -G in front of the access data.

eg

```
curl https://api.podbean.com/v1/analytics/podcastEngagementReports -G -d access_token=599d6a81a3c4e2464370f62dee5a987782899233  -d podcast_id:Ajv6jiApCl8 -d year=2021`
```